# curl command line works, php shell_exec() does not

Tags: php, ssl, curl

There are several other posts in reference to this problem.  The difference here is that I am willing to give out the troublesome url.

This works:
    `curl https://pas-gdl.overdrive.com/advanced-search`

This does not work:
    `$pagesource = shell_exec("curl https://pas-gdl.overdrive.com/advanced-search");`

I get the dreaded 51 error: "curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'pas-gdl.lib.overdrive.com'"

There is a wildcard ssl cert involved.  I have attempted to figure out what the command line curl is doing by default as a possible solution.  However, seeing as I am just executing the same command via shell_exec there should be zero difference.

The command line option produces the advanced-search html and the shell_exec does not.  Any information as to why would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `curl` invoked via shell runs under a different user than the one ran from the php script. There are a few solutions, first one that pops to mind is to use `--insecure` switch, which turns off SSL verification. The other one is to use a library such as [guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) so you don't have to fiddle with `shell_exec`. Third one is that you simply try to `$pagesource = file_get_contents('https://pas-gdl.overdrive.com/advanced-search")`.

Comment: I have tried `-k` which leads to a redirect error.  Then I use `-L` which allows for follow location.  This ends with the wrong html being acquired.  I attempted the `file_get_contents` but then get this error: `Failed to enable crypto in blah.php`.

Comment: Still fighting guzzle...

Comment: Guzzle contains copypaste examples, you don't even have to learn it properly..

Comment: I did exactly that and it output the wrong html as well.

Answer (score 0):

use [php curl](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php) instead

also  look into [how to curl https](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/)